# Data Not Shown In database Only shown array

Tags: javascript, php

when fill information in the below of add more address and then click for new address on add more address and fill data only previous filled data display not display the new data in databse only display array

```
    <h3>Delivery Address</h3>

            <form name="register" method="post" action="insert.php" >
                name<br /><input name="name" type="text"  size="20" /><br />
                email<br /><input name="email" type="text" size="20" /><br />
                password<br /><input name="password" type="password"  size="20" /><br />
                address:<br>
                Line 1<br /><input name="address" type="text"  size="20" /><br />
                city<br /><input name="city" type="text"  size="20" /><br />
                state<br /><input name="state" type="text"  size="20" /><br />

 <div id="itemRows">
 <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="add more address" /><br>
      Line1 <br><input type="text" name="address1" size="20" /><br/> 
   city<br> <input type="text"  size="20" name="city1" /> <br /> 
   state<br /><input name="state1"  type="text"  size="20" /><br /> 

  </div>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />  
 </form>
 <script>
  var rowNum = 0;
 function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Line1 <input type="text" name="address1"     size="20" value="'+frm.address1.value+'"> city<input type="text" name="city1"   value="'+frm.city1.value+'">state <input type="text" name="state1" size="20"    value="'+frm.state1.value+'"> <input type="button" value="Remove"    onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"></p>';
jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
 frm.address1.value = '';
frm.city1.value = '';
frm.state1.value = '';
}
 </script><script>
 function removeRow(rnum) {
  jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();}</script>
```

Comment: you are probably overwriting your data. add a third set and fill it out; if the only data you get is from the third set, you are overwriting (the form elements appear the share the same names).

Comment: what to do now  plz help

Comment: did you try what i suggested? (if so, what was the result?)

Comment: i do not know what to do please tell me again

Comment: oh! are you saying you have no data, just an empty array?

Comment: when i add the data in add more address's fileds if default can be filled it show data when click on add more and fill data then display array in database

Comment: I'm sorry but that does not make sense. I cannot understand what you are trying to say. Please use complete sentences with punction. An example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would probably be very helpful.